# EJB: Incompatible conflicting binding at java:module/env/

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I am deploying war to JBoss using Arquillian:

I see from the log that my class was successfully deployed:

```
14:10:54,125 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-5) JNDI bindings for session bean named MyClass in deployment unit deployment "test.war" are as follows:
        java:global/test/MyClass!com.package.MyInterface
        java:app/test/MyClass!com.package.MyInterface
        java:module/MyClass!com.package.MyInterface
```

It loads another beans, after a while application fails with exception:

```
14:10:54,985 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "test.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011053: Incompatible conflicting binding at java:module/env/MyClass source: org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource@b5aac489
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:239)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:196)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:164)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:157)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
        ... 5 more

14:10:55,050 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011053: Incompatible conflicting binding at java:module/env/MyClass source: org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource@b5aac489"}}
```

> conflicting binding at java:module/env/MyClass

**Questions:**

1. Why did it start deploy `MyClass` again?
2. What is `java:module/env` namespace for?
3. I think, I am absolutely happy without `java:module/env/` how to switch it off?

Comment: the namespace is `java:module`, and its a standardized namespace. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html . As to the error, that's hard to explain without being able to see anything. Its not related to MyClass being deployed twice, it looks like a problem related to referencing the bean. Any resource-ref configuration somewhere, such as in your web.xml?

Comment: I scanned my project for `java:module/env` and for `resource-ref` and didn't find single mention. I can say that I have very big monolith project(`ear`) now I would like to deploy only `ejb` related war. Is it good idea?